# How to display places on a route of a given destination

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps, google-places, google-directions-api

I'm trying to add markers (for places) on a route. It's like getting directions in Google maps. There should be two text boxes for origin and destination. After click on submit button the map should display all the possible routes (for example there can be five routes to visit the same place) and important places on that route (for example hotels, gardens and railway stations etc. on that route).

I'm using Google Maps for this project so I want to know how I should do this and what Google APIs I should use? Also I'm using WAMP server and Dreamweaver CS5.

Comment: We do not really provide tutorials here. This site is more like a "I have this problem, I have tried this and this, here is the code, the problem is this and this, can you help me?" place.

Comment: Investigate the [RouteBoxer](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/routeboxer/docs/examples.html)

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at the Directions Service Google offers with their maps api: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions